# jmespath tuple from several depths

Tags: jmespath

Is there a jmespath expression that will convert this:

```
{ "a": 5
, "b": [ {"c":6}, {"c":7}, {"c":8}]
}
```

into this:

```
[ {"a":5, "c":6}
, {"a":5, "c":7}
, {"a":5, "c":8}
]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: I know that jmespath lacks the ability to reference parents, otherwise this could be implemented as `b[*].{a:../a,c:c}`.  I don't see a cross product operator, with which I could get the result with: `cross(to_array(a),b).{a:[0],c:[1].c}`.  Scanning through the docs I don't see anything else that might help.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

- jmespath query
- how to produce cross reference to parent object elements

### Solution

- This is possible with jmespath, but unfortunately the result has to be constructed manually, which obviously may not be what you want

### Example

> Given the following dataset ...

```
    { "a": 5
    , "b": [ {"c":6}, {"c":7}, {"c":8}]
    }
```

> ... the following jmespath query ...

```
    [
        @.{"a":"a","c":"b"[0].c}
        , @.{"a":"a","c":"b"[1].c}
        , @.{"a":"a","c":"b"[2].c}
    ]
```

> ... produces the following result

```
    [
      {"a":5, "c":6}
    , {"a":5, "c":7}
    , {"a":5, "c":8}
    ]
```

### Pitfalls

- Jmespath iterates over sequences quite brilliantly, but does not iterate over object keys (aka name-value pairs) with the same degree of flexibility